# Numbering instances of a component

Tags: vuejs2, nuxt.js

I'm building a static page with Nuxt. The page consists of several chapters of a longer text and includes footnotes. Footnotes are numbered and pick their content from an array corresponding with the number.
So far I'm setting each footnotes number manualy through a prop, but I'm looking for a way to automataically number the footnotes in the order they appear in the text - or, more broadly, to assign to a component instance a number depending on the order they come up in the template of the parent component.

I can get all instances of of a component with

```js
const footnotes = this.$children.filter(child => child.constructor.options.name === 'Footnote')
```

but how can I assign a number to each instance? As far as I can see I have no access to props from, say `footnotes[0]`, or do I? If so, how? Or am I completely off the rails here?

**Edit:**

Footnotes are not within a v-for loop. They just appear inside the template of the parent component. Parent does not do anything special atm. It just sets the available notes:

```js
<template>
    <div>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur<footnote :nr="1" /> 
            sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut 
            labore et dolore<footnote :nr="2" /> magna aliquyam erat,
            sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo
            dolores<footnote :nr="3" /> et ea rebum.
        </p>
    </div>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue'
export default Vue.extend({
    data: () => {
        return {
            notes: [
                'this is a footnote',
                'this is another footnote',
                'this is again another footnote',
            ],
        }
    },
    beforeMount() {
        this.$store.commit('setActiveNotes', this.notes)
    },
})
</script>
```

footnote component just renders the text in a popup that is displayed on hover and links to the notes section on the same page:

```js
<template>
    <span
        class="inline-footnote has-tooltip"
        :id="'fn-' + no"
    >
        <nuxt-link class="" :to="'#note-' + no" v-bind:id="'fn-' + no">{{
            no
        }}</nuxt-link
        ><span class="tooltip">
            {{ noteContent }}
        </span>
    </span>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue'
export default Vue.extend({
    name: 'Footnote',
    props: {
        no: {
            type: [Number],
            default: 0,
        },
    },
    computed: {
        noteContent(): string {
            return this.$store.state.activeNotes[this.no - 1]
        },
    }
})
</script>
```

**Edit 2:** expanded on parent component code sample (see above)

Comment: Depending on what your code looks like, it may be done with a dynamic prop taken from the `index` of a `v-for`. In short: show us some relevant code please.

Comment: What is your parent (containing your `Footnote.vue` component) looks like?

Comment: @kissu I edited my question, please see above